# How to fade in when rotating URLs in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looping through an array of URLs keeping each one up in an iFrame based on the corresponding value in the durations array.

```
(function step(){
  $j('.marquee').attr('src',urls[i].innerHTML);
  setTimeout(step, parseInt(durations[i].innerHTML) * 1000);
  i = (i+1)%len;
})();
```

I want to have the new page fade in and for that I tried this":

```
 $j('.marquee').attr('src',urls[i].innerHTML).fadeIn();
```

But it's not behaving as I wanted it to. Is it because of the iFrame? How do I get the page inside the iFrame to fade in every time in the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot alter the loading of the page in iframe. Once you change the src of the iframe, loading will start as soon as the response is received.

What you can do is, temporarily hide the iframe when src changes, and call the fadeIn() function to give a nice effect. Something like below

```js
var durations = $('.durations');
var urls = $('.urls');
var i = 0;

(function step() {

  if (i < durations.length) {
    $('.marquee').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('.marquee').attr('src', urls[i].innerHTML);

    console.log(i);
    console.log(durations[i]);
    i = i + 1;
    setTimeout(step, parseInt(durations[i].innerHTML) * 200);

  }
})();
$('.marquee').on('load', function() {
  $('.marquee').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe class="marquee" frameborder="none"></iframe>
<div class='durations'>10</div>
<div class='durations'>20</div>
<div class='durations'>30</div>

<div class='urls'>https://www.bing.com</div>
<div class='urls'>https://www.bing.com</div>
<div class='urls'>https://www.bing.com</div>
```

If you want to keep the iframe visible, but to only fadein the content, then you have to add  script to loaded pages, which will keep the body hidden initially, then onload, fadeIn the content.
You cannot access the content from the parent page if the iframe content is of separate domain. If iframe content is of same domain then you can do this from the parent page also.

Comment: Everything is inside a network, so in the same domain. It's ok to hide the iframe when src changes and then call fadeIn()..... How do I do that? Thanks.